# Get all classes of an element in capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

Using capybara, is there a way to get all of the css classes of an element?  Looking at the documentation, I do not see any easy way of doing this.

Also, given an element, elem, and a css class, someclass, should `elem.has_css?('.someclass')` be equivalent to the jquery `$(elem).hasClass('someclass')`?

This particular test is using Selenium, because it involves javascript.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Element#[]](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#%5B%5D-instance_method) looks pretty easy to me:

```
find('div')[:class]
```

> Also, given an element, elem, and a css class, someclass, should elem.has_css?('.someclass') be equivalent to the jquery $(elem).hasClass('someclass')?

[Element#has_css?](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_css?-instance_method) checks for elements with specified CSS selector within element that method is invoked on. Jquery's [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) checks if an element has specified class.

**Update:** [Capybara matchers](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers) find elements/text within current element. `Element#has_css?` checks if an element contains element with specified css selector within it. If you want to check if element exists, use `page.has_css?`. Maybe matchers in form [expect(page).to have_css('div')](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#querying) would be better for you.

Comment: That works for getting the classes. I have a situation where elem[:class] returns "otherclass someclass", but elem.has_css?('.someclass') returns false. Does this make sense?

Comment: Could you point out the place in the README where it says that "Element#has_css checks if Element contains element with specified css selector within it"?  Also, if has_css? behaves the way you say it does, then I don't think the results of the jquery code and the ruby code in my question will necessarily be the same.

Comment: In reality I don't use and know jquery but I use a lot of capybara. Read [rdoc on has_css](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_css%3F-instance_method). I've updated answer